# Drop multiple databases using mysql command

Tags: mysql

I have many databases with different names.
I want to drop multiple databases, Is there any command since all names of db are different.

Eg: mysql db, Test db, live db.

Comment: I don't think there is a command to drop multiple databases in one statement. You could put a list of the databases in a text file and then run some sort of clever regex search-and-replace over it to produce a suitable statement.

Answer (score 13):

As of I know, there is no specific command/query to delete multiple databases without having a specific pattern in their names. Even I was asked to do the favor several times. So I researched and found no specific solution. Then I tried the below hack. It worked without giving much trouble. May be it could help for you too.

Take all the databases using the below command.

```
SHOW DATABASES ;
```

**Paste all of them in an excel/some other text file (I prefer NPP).** Keep the only names which you want to delete from the list. Dont forget to remove your working db's from the list.

**Add `DROP DATABASE` in front of those names.**

That's it simple. Copy & Paste all of those in your workbench. You can execute all of them in one shot.

Comment: MS Excel function : `=CONCATENER("drop database "; SUPPRESPACE(A1); ";")`

Comment: will this drop parallely?

Comment: @RNanthak No, in series.

Answer (score 6):

If you create a shell script this should remove all the databases. You will need to edit it to suit your needs.

```
DBUSER='user'
DBPASS='password'
SQLFILE='/path/to/file/databases.sql'

echo '* Dropping ALL databases'

DBS="$(mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -Bse 'show databases' | grep -v Database | grep -v database | grep -v mysql | grep -v information_schema)"

for db in $DBS; do
    echo "Deleting $db"
    mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -Bse "drop database $db; select sleep(0.1);"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

First run this query to produce a list of drop commands:

`` select CONCAT('drop database `', schema_name,'`;') as database_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name like '%DATABASES_TO_REMOVE%'  order by schema_name; ``

Then copy the output rows of this query and paste into a query window

In my case I then needed to remove the single-quotes (') surrounding the resulting command queries which I did using a simple find + replace (often Ctrl + H, replace ' with < empty >)

And execute (highlighting all of the drop statements in my case)!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunetly, there is nothing like that, unless you create your own function.

Answer (score 2):

simple bash script can be done this work

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/mshafee/file | while read line

do
        mysql -u username -p****** -h 0.0.0.0 -e "drop database $line;"

done
```

here provide username, password and IP address.